# Some questions about import/export file and overload operator in C++

Tags: c++, file, operator-overloading, fstream

I just have learn how to import/export file in C++. The problem is about writing a funcion read file FRACTION and export them to the screen. My teacher solves this one and teach us by this source code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct FRACTION{
    int numerator, denominator;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& inDev, FRACTION& p){

        inDev >> p.numerator >> p.denominator;
        return inDev;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outDev, FRACTION& p)
{
    outDev << p.numerator << "/" << p.denominator;
    return outDev;
}

PHANSO* ReadArrayFraction(istream& inDev, int& n){

        FRACTION* arr = NULL; cin >> n;
    if (inDev.fail() || n <= 0){ return arr; }
        arr = new FRACTION[n];
    if (arr != NULL){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            inDev >> arr[i];
            if (inDev.fail()){
                    delete[] arr; arr = NULL; break;
            }
        }
    }
        return arr;
}

void main(){
        ifstream fs("FRACTION.txt");
    if (fs.fail()){ cout << "Can't open the file" << endl; }
        int n;
        FRACTION* arr = ReadArrayFraction(fs, n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << arr[i] << endl;
        }
}
```

---

File FRACTION.txt:

```
3 4  
1 2 
2 3
```

---

I have 2 questions: 
1. How can we you this line "inDev >> arr[i]" to import transfer fraction of file into arr[i] ? I think that there are only characters in file Fraction.txt, they are not integer, so 2 object are not the same type but the compiler still works.
2. When I debug, this line "inDev >> arr[i]" has miss the first character of file and the funcion return NULL. In this situation, "inDev >> arr[i]" has miss "3". If I add other character such as "2", It will miss "2" and start the transferation at 3.
I don't understand those problems, so hope you will explan to me, thank you all!

Comment: Have you ever used `std::cin` to read integers? Why do you think it would be different using the input file stream to read an integer? In C++ an input stream is an input stream is an input stream... They all work the same.

Comment: Your teacher should attend a C++ course. There is a number of issues with the code. Input and output formats for the fractions are incompatible, no `const` in the `operator<<`, old-style arrays are used instead of vectors, the result of `ReadArrayFraction` is not checked, code formatting is bad... As for missing characters, perhaps you didn't pay attention to the `cin >> n;` statement (because code formatting is bad!) You need to specify the number of array elements before elements themselves.